# Error while taking a screenshot in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot in my app both with emulator and the phone and I keep getting these messages.
In my emulator I get these message:

[image: 1]

In my phone I get the following message:

```
Screenshots of this screen are not allowed
```

And it's just only one screen, the rest of the screens are yowrking alright. So if someone has any clue of why I can't please give me some advice.

Comment: Most likely, that screen has blocked screenshots using `FLAG_SECURE`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I read something about that, but how can I solve it?

Comment: You said that this is your app. Apparently, you put `FLAG_SECURE` on this screen. If you do not want `FLAG_SECURE` on this screen, you can remove your code that it putting `FLAG_SECURE` on this screen. If this screen is coming from a third-party library, contact the developers of that library to see if there are some options.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well in these case on that screen I'm using a third party library to reproduce videos if the petition has any, so I think in these case that is the problem, bu I'm not sure. I'm using vimeo library

Comment: Probably Vimeo has set this up to prevent people from recording their videos by recording the app's screen.